# Как настроить имитацию нажатия ctrl+v

Tags: python, клавиатура

Есть проблемка с питоном и его модулями имитирующими клавиатуру. У меня есть прога которая загружает расписание с моего учебного заведения в PDF формате и пытается скинуть его + сообщение в беседу группы в ВК, по итогу и загрузка файла в ВК, и печатание сообщения я решил реализовать через имитация копирования текста и последующую имитацию нажатия ctrl+v, но он не всегда имитирует "вставку" в этом то и есть вся проблема. В общем то вот часть кода с которой проблема:

```
#здесь имитация загрузки PDF
driver.get(beseda)
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click (x=249, y=790,clicks=1, button='left')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click (x=251, y=650,clicks=1, button='left')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click (x=537, y=209,clicks=1, button='left')
time.sleep(3)
pyperclip.copy (PUT+ss+year+ss+month+ss+day+TYPEF) #ss:=\\
SHELL.SendKeys('^v')
pyautogui.press ('enter')
time.sleep(time_for_download)
#здесь отправка 2 сообщений
pyperclip.copy(text+day+space+name_month)
pyautogui.click (x=397, y=718,clicks=1, button='left')
time.sleep(1)
SHELL.SendKeys('^v')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press ('enter')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click (x=571, y=790,clicks=1, button='left')
time.sleep(1)
pyperclip.copy("Бот находится в бета-тесте! Не бейте и не унижайте его!")
time.sleep(1)
SHELL.SendKeys('^v')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press ('enter')
```

p.s. Я уже переходил на pyautogui полностью- ситуация не меняется

p.p.s Если помогут с альтернативой имитации мыши и клавы то будет шик!

Comment: уточните куда идёт вставка ? в браузере ?

Comment: Да, в окошко с указанием пути и в блоке с сообщением